# Vega-lite / add dynamic layer based on range defined by joinaggregate columns

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, deneb

I'm building a milestone trend analysis chart with vega-lite. The vega-lite chart pulls a dataset (milestone date and finish date), calculates the range for the scales based on the subranges and plots the time series of the milestones correctly. Now I need to overlay the chart with a diagonal line and/or a triangle area in the lower right part of the chart for visually excluding the non valid part of the chart.

I tried several options:

using either milestone date or finish date series from my dataset for plotting the line / area doesn't cover the entire range of the chart:

[line/area not spanning entire range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB8YN.png)

Hard coding the dates would work, however, when selecting different milestones the line / area wouldn't adapt.

When referencing parameters/signal for encoding no rule / area is displayed.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

[desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G80gT.png)

This is the code used for creating above visualization:

```
{
  "width": 500,
  "height": 500,
  "title": {
    "text": "Milestone Trend Analysis"
  },
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "transform": [
    {
      "joinaggregate": [
        {
          "op": "min",
          "field": "Report Date",
          "as": "Report_Date_min"
        },
        {
          "op": "max",
          "field": "Report Date",
          "as": "Report_Date_max"
        },
        {
          "op": "min",
          "field": "Milestone Finish Date",
          "as": "Milestone_Finish_Date_min"
        },
        {
          "op": "max",
          "field": "Milestone Finish Date",
          "as": "Milestone_Finish_Date_max"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum.Report_Date_min < datum.Milestone_Finish_Date_min ? datum.Report_Date_min : datum.Milestone_Finish_Date_min",
      "as": "Time_range_min"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum.Report_Date_max > datum.Milestone_Finish_Date_max ? datum.Report_Date_max : datum.Milestone_Finish_Date_max",
      "as": "Time_range_max"
    }
  ],
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "Time_range_min_p",
      "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['Time_range_min']"
    },
    {
      "name": "Time_range_max_p",
      "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['Time_range_max']"
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "name": "milestone_trace",
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Report Date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {
            "title": "Report Date",
            "grid": true,
            "orient": "top"
          },
          "scale": {
            "domainMin": {
              "expr": "Time_range_min_p"
            },
            "domainMax": {
              "expr": "Time_range_max_p"
            }
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Milestone Finish Date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {
            "title": "Milestone Date",
            "grid": true
          },
          "scale": {
            "domainMin": {
              "expr": "Time_range_min_p"
            },
            "domainMax": {
              "expr": "Time_range_max_p"
            }
          }
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "Task Code",
          "scale": {
            "scheme": "pbiColorNominal"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "milestone_mark",
      "mark": {
        "type": "circle",
        "opacity": 1,
        "strokeWidth": 1,
        "size": 30,
        "filled": false,
        "tooltip": true
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Report Date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {
            "title": "Report Date",
            "grid": true
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Milestone Finish Date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {
            "title": "Milestone Date",
            "grid": true
          }
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "Task Code",
          "scale": {
            "scheme": "pbiColorNominal"
          }
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {
            "field": "Task Code",
            "title": "Milestone Type"
          },
          {
            "field": "Milestone Finish Date",
            "title": "Finish Date",
            "type": "temporal"
          },
          {
            "field": "Report Date",
            "title": "Report Date",
            "type": "temporal"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {
            "a": "2021-12-31",
            "b": "2021-12-31"
          },
          {
            "a": "2024-08-25",
            "b": "2024-08-25"
          }
        ]
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "name": "date_equity",
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "strokeDash": [8, 4],
            "strokeWidth": 1,
            "color": "red"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "a",
              "type": "temporal"
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "b",
              "type": "temporal"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "whitespace",
          "mark": {
            "type": "area",
            "fill": "white"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "a",
              "type": "temporal"
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "b",
              "type": "temporal"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "style": {
      "cell": {"stroke": "transparent"}
    }
  }
}
```

data looks like this:

| Report Date | Milestone Finish Date | Task Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-01 | 2023-07-01 | MSFT |
| 2023-06-01 | 2023-06-20 | MSFT |
| 2023-05-01 | 2023-06-10 | MSFT |

the full dataset for producing the screenshots can be found here
[csv file on github](https://github.com/hofphil/deneb/blob/main/MTA_Sample_Data.csv)

Comment: You need to provide a full spec with data for people to be able to help. Or upload a sample.pbix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was to get a data column that includes both global min and max value from both input columns ("Report Date" and "Milestone Finish Date"). This column can be then used for plotting both line and area. This column is obtained by calculate transform based on the internal dataset field "__row__" (see code)

Code is as follows:

```
{
  "width": 500,
  "height": 500,
  "title": {
    "text": "Milestone Trend Analysis"
  },
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "transform": [
    {
      "joinaggregate": [
        {
          "op": "min",
          "field": "Report Date",
          "as": "Report_Date_min"
        },
        {
          "op": "max",
          "field": "Report Date",
          "as": "Report_Date_max"
        },
        {
          "op": "min",
          "field": "Milestone Finish Date",
          "as": "Milestone_Finish_Date_min"
        },
        {
          "op": "max",
          "field": "Milestone Finish Date",
          "as": "Milestone_Finish_Date_max"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum.Report_Date_min < datum.Milestone_Finish_Date_min ? datum.Report_Date_min : datum.Milestone_Finish_Date_min",
      "as": "Global_min"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum.Report_Date_max > datum.Milestone_Finish_Date_max ? datum.Report_Date_max : datum.Milestone_Finish_Date_max",
      "as": "Global_max"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum['__row__'] <= 0 ? datum.Global_min : datum.Global_max",
      "as": "Time_range"
    }
  ],
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "Global_min_p",
      "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['Global_min']"
    },
    {
      "name": "Global_max_p",
      "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['Global_max']"
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "name": "milestone_trace",
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Report Date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {
            "title": "Report Date",
            "grid": true,
            "orient": "top"
          },
          "scale": {
            "domainMin": {
              "expr": "Global_min_p"
            },
            "domainMax": {
              "expr": "Global_max_p"
            }
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Milestone Finish Date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {
            "title": "Milestone Date",
            "grid": true
          },
          "scale": {
            "domainMin": {
              "expr": "Global_min_p"
            },
            "domainMax": {
              "expr": "Global_max_p"
            }
          }
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "Task Code",
          "scale": {
            "scheme": "pbiColorNominal"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "milestone_mark",
      "mark": {
        "type": "circle",
        "opacity": 1,
        "strokeWidth": 1,
        "size": 30,
        "filled": false,
        "tooltip": true
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Report Date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {
            "title": "Report Date",
            "grid": true
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Milestone Finish Date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {
            "title": "Milestone Date",
            "grid": true
          }
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "Task Code",
          "scale": {
            "scheme": "pbiColorNominal"
          }
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {
            "field": "Task Code",
            "title": "Milestone Type"
          },
          {
            "field": "Milestone Finish Date",
            "title": "Finish Date",
            "type": "temporal"
          },
          {
            "field": "Report Date",
            "title": "Report Date",
            "type": "temporal"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "date_equity",
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "strokeDash": [8, 4],
        "strokeWidth": 1,
        "color": "red"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Time_range",
          "type": "temporal"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Time_range",
          "type": "temporal"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "whitespace",
      "mark": {
        "type": "area",
        "fill": "white"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Time_range",
          "type": "temporal"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Time_range",
          "type": "temporal"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "style": {
      "cell": {"stroke": "transparent"}
    }
  }
}
```

Solution looks like this
[image: animated visual image]

Answer (score 3):

According to the Vega-Lite documentation ([link](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/area.html#area-chart)), it looks like the area chart may expect that one of the axes include a quantitative variable (rather than two temporal variables, as in your case). I noticed a similar behavior as to what you're describing when attempting to replicate your use case on a smaller, toy example with two temporal axes.

Perhaps one workaround would be to leverage a dual-axis encoding with the area (triangle) dynamically generated. While I was not able to test it on your exact data, take a look at the following example (which is based on the simple [line chart example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/line) in the editor):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Google's stock price over time.",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"}],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal", "axis": {"orient": "top"}},
        "y": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "aggregate": [
            {"op": "min","field": "date","as": "min_date"},
            {"op": "max","field": "date","as": "max_date"}
          ]
        },
        {"fold": ["min_date", "max_date"]},
        {"calculate": "datum.value==datum.min_date ? 0 : 100", "as": "yvalue"}
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "area", "fill": "white"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "value", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "yvalue", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is what you would see if you change the `fill` to "red" and unhide the dual axis by removing `"axis": null`. Note that the blue line here is fairly boring and just shows along the diagonal.

[image]

**UPDATE 6/1**
For the structure of the provided dataset (which already computes the desired `Time_range_min` and `Time_range_max`), it should be straightforward to specify the new layer for the triangle as follows:

```
{
  "transform": [
    {
      "aggregate": [
        {"op": "min","field": "Time_range_min","as": "min_date"},
        {"op": "max","field": "Time_range_max","as": "max_date"}
      ]
    },
    {"fold": ["min_date", "max_date"]},
    {"calculate": "datum.value==datum.min_date ? 0 : 100", "as": "yvalue"}
  ],
  "mark": {"type": "area", "fill": "white"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "value", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "yvalue", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information. However, it doesn't seem to fully apply to my case, as I already struggle with adding the line mark. My visual requires the line mark to span the date-range including the sub-ranges of "Report Date" and "Milestone Finish Date". In the example given above the line-mark is encoded in x and y both with field date. I don't have such a data field, and would need to construct it from the sub-ranges.

Comment: @PhilippHof, if possible, consider editing your question to add a sample dataset to your spec so that it is easier to test on your exact use case.This approach may still work, but you will need to update the transforms to apply to "Report Date" rather than "date"; "Milestone Finish Date" would not be needed as the dual axis encoding will take care of spanning that range.

Comment: i've linked the full dataset used in the code above; main challenge is that ranges of "Report Date" and "Milestone Finish Date" in general don't have the same range

Comment: @PhilippHof looking at your full dataset, it should be straightforward to create the mark as you have already computed the min/max for the range. Rather than using "date" as the field in the aggregate transform, simply change it to "Time_range_min" and "Time_range_max" as so:

"aggregate": [
  {"op": "min","field": "Time_range_min","as": "min_date"},
  {"op": "max","field": "Time_range_max","as": "max_date"}
]

You should then be able to use the layer I provided above with your own data.